# Java Android app first activity using ViewPagerAdapter from second activity

Tags: java, android

My Java Android app has two activities that inherit from my BaseActivity.  My BaseActivity has a ViewPagerAdapter and a function called AddCard.  On my first activity, I can usually add a card with no problem.  But when I switch to the second and back again, the same function wants to use the second activity's instance of my ViewPagerAdapter.

Here's some code:

```
static ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
```

…

```
static void addCard(Long fragmentId, String title, Serializable specs) {
    Log.i("BaseActivity:addCard", "fragmentId: " + fragmentId);
    Log.i("BaseActivity:addCard", "pageCount = " + viewPagerAdapter.getCount());

    for (int i = 0; i < viewPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        Log.i("BaseActivity:addCard", "viewPagerAdapter.getItem(" + i + "): " + viewPagerAdapter.getItem(i));
        if (fragmentId == viewPagerAdapter.getLongId(i)) {
            Log.i("BaseActivity:addCard", "adding card title: " + title);
            Log.i("BaseActivity:addCard", "adding card fragmentId: " + fragmentId);
            //Thinks it's on Activity 2.
            ((BaseFragment) viewPagerAdapter.getItem(i)).addCard(title, specs);
            break;
        }
    }
    Log.i("BaseActivity:addCard", "exiting addCard");
}
```

Comment: It's because `viewPagerAdapter` is `static`. Any particular reason you made it so?

Comment: Hello Mike M.  Thank you for the response.  It's static because my AddPage function is static because it's called by the OnClickListener of the POSITIVE_BUTTON on my dialog, and I get "Non-static method...cannot be referenced from a static context" if I don't keep it static.

Comment: Well, it shouldn't be `static`, neither should that method. If you're creating the `Dialog` as an inner class, then it has access to that method, and can call it directly. If the `Dialog` is in a separate class – e.g., in a `DialogFragment` – then you can implement a callback `interface` to relay the click action back to the `Activity` instance, where it can call that method directly itself. We'd need to see your setup to give specific suggestions, though.

Comment: Apparently, I was using `static` everywhere because my fragments and dialogs had things like `MyActivity.addCard()` when it should have said `((MyActivity)getActivity()).addCard()`.  Thanks for your help.